# rabbitmq-plugins.bat enable rabbitmq_management

Tags: django, python-3.x, rabbitmq, celery

I install Erl7.3 and rabbitmq-server 3.6.2. I using Win7 32bit. After installing when I run 'rabbitmq-server' command it gives:

```
ERROR: node with name "rabbit" already running on "admin-PC"
```

When I run 'net stop RabbitMQ && net start RabbitMQ' it stopped RabbitMQ service and restarted successfully.

After that When I run "rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management", it gives following errors and nothing is shown at http://localhost:15672:

```
Plugin configuration unchanged.

Applying plugin configuration to rabbit@admin-PC... failed.
Error: {undef,[{crypto,module_info,[attributes],[]},
               {rabbit_misc,module_attributes,1,
                            [{file,"src/rabbit_misc.erl"},{line,817}]},
               {rabbit_misc,'-all_module_attributes/1-fun-0-',3,
                            [{file,"src/rabbit_misc.erl"},{line,837}]},
               {lists,foldl,3,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1262}]},
               {rabbit_boot_steps,find_steps,1,
                                  [{file,"src/rabbit_boot_steps.erl"},
                                   {line,40}]},
               {rabbit_boot_steps,run_boot_steps,1,
                                  [{file,"src/rabbit_boot_steps.erl"},
                                   {line,26}]},
               {rabbit,start_apps,1,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,451}]},
               {rabbit_plugins,ensure,1,
                               [{file,"src/rabbit_plugins.erl"},{line,52}]}]}
```

For your information, I set environmental variables as:

```
'Variable name: ERLANG_HOME', 'Variable value: C:\Program Files\erl7.3'; 

'Variable name: RABBITMQ_SERVER', 'Variable value: C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.2'
```

and system path "%ERLANG_HOME%;;%RABBITMQ_SERVER%\sbin"

How to resolve this errors?

Answer (score 0):

rabbitmq management plugin needs the `crypto`pakage to work.

see:

```
Error: {undef,[{crypto,module_info,[attributes],[]},
               {rabbit_misc,module_attributes,1,
```

Try to use the Erlang `18.3` version.

**EDIT**

> After installing when I run 'rabbitmq-server' command it gives:
>
> ERROR: node with name "rabbit" already running on "admin-PC"

This is normal since `rabbitmq-server` starts the server, but you have rabbitmq installed and running as windows service.

And you should use the 64 bit version

Comment: I installed latest version of Erlang 18.3, I also installed crypto 1.4.1 separately but same errors continue. Error messages also remain same.